# Voltage leakage on Netcomm Ethernet over power

Tags: ethernet, power

I've got a Netcomm Ethernet over Power device. I noticed (via a small shock) that when no connected equipment is grounded, the ethernet lines float 60-100v (this is 240v mains) above ground (as measured on a high impedance multimeter).

It all still works, but I'm wondering if this is normal or a fault condition?

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. The same thing would be true of a wire that wasn't connected to anything at all. It can float anywhere it wants to so long as there's no load placed on it. This is one of the reasons equipment should be grounded.

Comment: Hmm. I know about mains hum (buzz when you touch an RCA, or a 50Hz sine wave on an unconnected scope). But 100v into 1M seems a bit excessive, as does a mild shock, or a spark when you disconnect ground. I've grounded my network through a convenient desktop PC now (the Netcomm box itself has 2-wire mains and no ground tag).